# Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am new to angularjs and I am facing this error while i run my test using karma-jasmine

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/nomod?p0=app
  at bower_components/angular/angular.js:2297

```
describe('LoginController', function () {

beforeEach(module('app'));

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
$controller = _$controller_;
}));

describe('homeBtn', function () {
    it('whether its sign in or register', function () {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('LoginController', { $scope: $scope });

        $scope.homeBtn("Register");
        expect($scope.signinerror).toBeFalsy();
        expect($scope.tryagain).toBeFalsy();
        expect($scope.registererror).toBeFalsy();
        expect($scope.modal_title).toBe("Register");
    }); 
});

});
```

this is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngWebSocket','ng.epoch']);
```

This is my Login Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginController',['$rootScope','$scope','$location','$http', function($rootScope,$scope,$location,$http){
$scope.homeBtn = function(keyvalue){
    $scope.signinerror=false;
    $scope.tryagain=false;
    $scope.registererror=false;

    if(keyvalue == "Register"){

        $scope.modal_title="Register";
        $scope.reg=true;
    }
    else{
        $scope.reg=false;
        $scope.modal_title="Sign In";
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/epoch/dist/css/epoch.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/index.css">

</head>
<body>
    <ng-view> </ng-view>    
    <!--Bower Components-->
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-websocket/dist/angular-websocket.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/epoch/dist/js/epoch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/ng-epoch/ng-epoch.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/js-md5/src/md5.js"></script>

    <!--MainJS-->
         <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>


        <!--Controllers-->
        <script src="app/js/Controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
        <script src="app/js/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>


        <!--custom js files-->

        <script src="app/js/libraries/common.js"></script>
        <script src="app/js/libraries/smoothie.js"></script>
        <!--directives-->


        <!--factories-->
        <script src="app/js/Factories/websocketservice.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my karma config file

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/**/*.js',
  'test/**/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
 })
 }
```

Comment: Any idea how you solved this issue?